# Check that process is running

Tags: bash, command-line

I have the following bash code which checks that a process is running:

```
is_running() {
 ps `cat "$pid_file"` > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

The problem is that `is_running` is always evaluated to `true`.

`$pid_file` contains a process ID that isn't listed when I run `ps`.
I would like in this case, `is_running` to return `false`.

How can I modify it for that purpose?

Comment: Do not use `cat` this way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `-p` option:

```
ps -p PID
```

In `bash`, i would simply do:

```
is_running() { ps -p $(<"$1") &>/dev/null ;}
```

and will give the filename as an argument to the function:

```
is_running /pid/file
```

---

- You need to start using the newer command substitution syntax `$()` instead of the arcane `` `...` ``
- `bash` supports a shorthand (`&>`) for indicating the redirection of STDOUT and STDERR

Comment: ++; as an aside: while using `-p` is definitely the right thing to do, because it is the POSIX-compliant way to pass a PID, in all `ps` implementation I've come across something like `ps $$` works too.